# How can I start the node red with forever in my linux server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever, node-red

I am installed node-red with npm and able to run the node red by just typing the 'node-red' in terminal that's it. But how can I run the node red in linux server with forever command ? I want node red running continuously.

Comment: what have you tried? did `forever node-red` not work? is forever installed?

Comment: I tried with forever node-red, but it says 'cannot start forever' and 'node-red does not exist'.

Comment: You run node-red as you would any other node.js app - there is nothing special about it. I use `forever start /path/to/node-red/red.js --settings /path/to/my/node-red/settings.js`

Comment: Where can I find the red.js and setting.js file in server?

Comment: I find out red.js file in there in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js`

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a script as a daemon. But first install forever globally: `npm -g install forever` (you'll need root privileges to do that). Then issue command `forever start /path/to/node-red red.js`.

Comment: I have installed forever in my linux server. I am already running some node js servers with forever start command. But I didn't find any .js file to start a with it. like you said 'forever start /path/to/node-red red.js'

Answer (score 0):

First you should've noticed that when you installed nod-red, it says the path to your file, so for me it was 
`/usr/bin/node-red` -> `/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js`

Then, eventually I run this command and it works smoothly.

```
forever --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
```